# Again about routing

Tags: routing, forwarding

Have a problem with primitive routing.
Have a CentOs with 3 NICs (1 external). I want to confgure forwarding between two internal. Config:

eth0 - 192.168.1.105 \ 24

eth1 - 10.10.10.1 \ 25

eth2 - 10.10.10.129\ 25

Clients have a gateway 10.10.10.1 and 10.10.10.129 (depending on subnet)

Here is  route:
[image]
sysctl.conf net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1 - enabled.
When i'm test ping from clients, clients can ping their gateway, other NIC ip(ex. client with ip 10.10.10.10 pings 10.10.10.1(gw) and 10.10.10.129), but cannot ping any client from neighbour subnet. There is the problem?

Comment: Is your firewall blocking?

Comment: set chkconfig iptables off

Comment: What does `# iptables -L` show?

Comment: Thanks for looking in this topic! in FORWARDING chain it was REJECT all

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @garethTheRed, the problem was in `iptables`. In FORWARDING chain it was set REJECT all I've deleted this chain `iptables -F FORWARDING` (rather destructuve, but i'm not very familiar with `iptables`) then added:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 -j ACCEPT
```

Works great!